# How to fix the code which is interrupted by OS due to out-of-memory & optimize the code?

Tags: python, numpy, out-of-memory

I have a problem with creating numpy.ndarray.
This is the part of code. 
.....

```
def make_weighted_pedge(graph):

    number_of_nodes = len(graph.nodes())
    l_ij = np.full([number_of_nodes, number_of_nodes], np.nan)

    # If two nodes are adjacent, its minimum path length is 1
    for node in graph.nodes():
        neighbor_nodes = [n for n in graph.neighbors(node)]

        for adj_node in neighbor_nodes:
            l_ij[int(node) - 1][int(adj_node) - 1] = 1
            l_ij[int(adj_node) - 1][int(node) - 1] = 1
```

After I run this code, I get this error message!

```
"Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)"
```

Comment: `len(graph.nodes())` - how many nodes are there?

Comment: len(graph.nodes()) is approximately over 20,0000. Is there another way to solve this problem? - @wwii

Answer (score 0):

`np.nan` is a float. `np.full(...)` produces an ndarray of dtype `int64`.  Your 20k x 20k ndarray will be ~3.2Gb.

```
In [45]: np.full((1000,1000),np.nan).nbytes
Out[45]: 8000000    # times 400 for shape (20k,20k)
```

It doesn't look like you need floats so you could reduce the size by a factor of 4 or 8 using dtypes `np.uint16` or `np.uint8`

```
In [47]: np.zeros((1000,1000), dtype=np.uint16).nbytes
Out[47]: 2000000

In [48]: np.zeros((1000,1000), dtype=np.uint8).nbytes
Out[48]: 1000000
```

`np.uint16` will limit the max path length to 65535 and `np.uint8` will limit it to 255.

If you need the `np.nan` values, the best you can do is a factor of four using `np.float16`

```
np.full((number_of_nodes, number_of_nodes),np.nan,dtype=np.float16)
```

---

[Data type objects](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)